# Making default value in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have created a report out of Pentaho Report Designer. 
I uploaded the report on Pentaho User Console.

I have several dropdowns e.g. Order ID, Line Item ID, Date.

Once I select Order ID, Line Item ID is filtered and is displayed.

I created a 'All Line Item' value that displays all line item.

I want to make it as a default value.

How to have a default value in Report Designer? 
The drop downs are added using 'add parameter'. What settings do I need to have in Parameter of  'Line Item ID' to make 'All Line Item' as default value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your parameter, set default value or default Value formula[image]